# How to apply condition on grandparent from within the child class in Less

Tags: html, css, less

```
<div class="grandParent active"> /*active class added dynamically*/
   <div class="parent1">
    <div class="childOfParent1">  Some Text  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent2">
     <div class="childOfParent2">  Some Text  </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Using Less how can i apply the child text color depending on grandParent class

```
.grandParent {
  .parent1 {
    .childOfParent1 {
      color : red;
      .grandParent:not(active) .parent1 .childOfParent1 {
        color : green;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above is possible using the below code but i do not want to repeat the code

```
.grandParent {
  .parent1 {
    .childOfParent1 {
      color : red;
    }
  }
  &:not(active) .parent1 .childOfParent1 {
      color : green;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most maintainable code would be something like this I guess:

```
.parent {
    .child {
        color: green;
        .grandParent.active & {color: red}
    }
}
```

Or less DRY (if you really want to get use of `:not`):

```
.parent {
    .child {
        .grandParent              & {color: red}
        .grandParent:not(.active) & {color: green}
    }
}
```

See [Changing selector order](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order) for more details on such `&` usage.

---

Following the comments below here's another variant:

```
.grandParent {
    .parent {
        .child {
            color: green;
            .active& {color: red}
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Well, slightly offtopic]
Though if really takes into getting it maintainable, there're a few remarks:

1. Avoid too specific selectors (so for this example I think either `.grandParent` or `.parent` are redundant actually).
2. Never nest for the sake of nesting. Sometimes nesting is good but sometimes it's extremely ugly (see [this nice brief answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938060/2712740) for just a few of many reasons for never doing it blindly).
3. DRY != maintainable. Often repeating one or two classes for "flat" styles are much better than writing a bloated and cluttered class hierarchy (Usually for such cases mixins and/or selector interpolation works better than plain nesting). E.g. instead of making it more easy modifiable (usually this is the only reason for being too heavy on DRY)  think if you could write it the way you'll never want it to be modified at all.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, but my .parent1 selector is enclosed by .grandParent selector. The above solution will only work if the .parent1 selector is outside of the .grandParent selector. Is there any way i can apply condition on .grandParent from within the .grandParent selector?

Comment: @seenimurugan: No mate, since the `&` is added at the end, the compiled CSS selector would be like `.grandParent:not(.active) .parent1 .childOfParent1`. So effectively the structure is the same. Just the order of nesting the selectors in Less is modified to suit the needs.

Comment: [Here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/LwDpF) is a sample for you using the code in the answer.

Comment: Hi Harry, thanks a lot for your time, But as i said earlier when the .parent1 is inside the .grandParent, the compiled output is `.grandParent .grandParent .parent1 .childOfParent1 {`
  `color: #ff0000;`
`}`
`.grandParent:not(.active) .grandParent .parent1 .childOfParent1 {`
  `color: #008000;`
`}` . So the 'some Text' will not be colored as i expected.

Comment: With this approach the `.parent1` should not be inside `.grandParent` in the actual Less file mate. The nesting should start with `.parent1`. But if for some reason you are not in favor of this approach then you may have to try something like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/LwDpF) but this in a way is repetitive coding too.

Comment: I want to write maintainable code and should also clearly understandable by not repeating and separating things out. Anyway thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63483/discussion-between-seenimurugan-and-harry).