# Is there a smarter way to write this using CSS/LESS?

Tags: css, less

I'm a new LESS/CSS user working with some nested rules.  What I have so far is working just fine - my question is whether it's written correctly, or if there's a better way to approach it?  Perhaps I'm just over-thinking this so feel free to tell me that too.

I am attempting to change the accent color of a dropdown (affecting the header, a indicator arrow, and the footer) by specifying only an accent color class on the dropdown - as illustrated by this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tq5gjbw9/

My LESS looks like this:

```
.dropdown {

    & .dropdown-menu
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
        border-radius: 0;
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        border-top: solid 5px @color_grey;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        box-shadow:4px 4px 0 rgba(100,100,100,0.08);
    }
    &.pinkAccent .dropdown-menu
    {
        border-top: solid 5px @color_pink;
    }
    &.greenAccent .dropdown-menu
    {
        border-top: solid 5px @color_green;
    }
    &.blueAccent .dropdown-menu
    {
        border-top: solid 5px @color_blue;
    }

    & .dropdown-toggle {
        position:relative;
    }

    &.open .dropdown-toggle:after
    {
        content: " ";
        background-color: transparent;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        right: auto;
        margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
        padding: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        border-top: 0;
        border-bottom: 6px solid @color_grey; 
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    }
    &.open.pinkAccent .dropdown-toggle:after
    {
        border-bottom-color: @color_pink;
    }
    &.open.greenAccent .dropdown-toggle:after
    {
        border-bottom-color: @color_green;
    }
    &.open.blueAccent .dropdown-toggle:after
    {
        border-bottom-color: @color_blue;
    }

    & .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        -moz-transition: all 0;
        -o-transition: all 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 0;
        transition: all 0;
        outline: 0;
        &:hover,
        &:focus
        {
            background-color: #e8e8e8;
            background-image: none;
            filter: none;
        }

    }

    & .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header {
        background-color: @color_grey;
        color: @color_white;
        margin:0;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    &.pinkAccent .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header {
        background-color: @color_pink;
        color: @color_white;
    }
    &.greenAccent .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header {
        background-color: @color_green;
        color: @color_white;
    }
    &.blueAccent .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header {
        background-color: @color_blue;
        color: @color_white;
    }

    & .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-footer {
        background-color: @color_grey;
        color: @color_white;
        margin:0;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    &.pinkAccent .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-footer {
        background-color: @color_pink;
        color: @color_white;
    }
    &.greenAccent .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-footer {
        background-color: @color_green;
        color: @color_white;
    }
    &.blueAccent .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-footer {
        background-color: @color_blue;
        color: @color_white;
    }

}
```

I feel like a lot of the selectors are overly wordy.  If we look at the just the first few rules, I'm wondering if there's a way to put the accents "into" the  & .dropdown-menu {} rule so it's not repeated...  I feel like I'm almost looking for a placeholder keyword or something:

```
.dropdown {

    &[placeholder] .dropdown-menu
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
        border-radius: 0;
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        border-top: solid 5px @color_grey;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        box-shadow:4px 4px 0 rgba(100,100,100,0.08);

        [placeholder=".pinkAccent"] 
        {
            border-top: solid 5px @color_pink;
        }
        [placeholder=".greenAccent "] 
        {
            border-top: solid 5px @color_green;
        }
        [placeholder=".blueAccent"] 
        {
            border-top: solid 5px @color_blue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: at a minimum you could combine similarly defined styles like `&.blueAccent .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-footer` and `&.blueAccent .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header` as `&.blueAccent .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-footer, &.blueAccent .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header`

Comment: You should check out code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you seen this?  Mixins are a beautiful thing: http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505932/how-to-apply-condition-on-grandparent-from-within-the-child-class-in-less/26506150 which enables you to do `.dropdown {.dropdownmenu{ .pinkAccent& {
     border-top: solid 5px pink;
    }}}`

Comment: Using your code and applying some modifications.. and the result is here: http://codepen.io/madcorp/pen/vCLxB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like [Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) help to avoid repetitive code. Here's a simplified example for "accents of the drop-down menu" part (also using [Selector Interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-selectors) and [Variable Name Referencing](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names)):

```
.dropdown {
    // use accent mixin:
    .accent(pink);
    .accent(green);
    .accent(blue);

    // define accent mixin:
    .accent(@name) {
        @color: "color_@{name}";
        &.@{name}Accent .dropdown-menu {
            border-top: solid 5px @@color;
        }
    }
}
```

This example requires Less v2.x, for earlier versions you will need escaped color keywords so that they won't be converted to hex color values, i.e. use `.accent(~'pink');` instead of `.accent(pink);` etc.

---

Obviously since you use same colors for other styles you probably would want to put these other color depended styles into that mixin too (I used `.accent` name for the mixin just for short).